# Custom renderer not triggering listener for ajax event

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, broadcast, custom-renderer

Hello again JSF Gurus.

I am looking for help on custom renderers and ajax handlers. Our project cannot use the normal radio button and check box renderers as they render in tables and this is against our corporate standards. Neither can we use third party component libraries.

We have a custom renderer that we have used in a few projects now that works fine. However, on this particular project, I need to render the ajax click handler for some radio buttons. Following the advice in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659287/add-ajax-behaviour-to-jsf-renderer) I have added the call to `RenderKitUtils.renderSelectOnclick();` and whilst it appears to render the same javaScript as the standard renderer, and indeed, firebug network panel shows the outgoing request, my value change listener is not being fired and I am looking for help as to why (it fires perfectly well with the standard renderer)

Some code:
Firstly, the creation of the ajax handler (the radio button is created programatically)

```
          AjaxBehavior valueChangeAction = (AjaxBehavior) FacesUtils.getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);

        valueChangeAction.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new ProbeQuestionListener(currentQuestion, "probeDiv" + questionNumber,
            probeDiv));

        selectUI.addClientBehavior("valueChange", valueChangeAction);
        valueChangeAction.setRender(Collections.singletonList("probeDiv" + questionNumber));
```

Wih the standard renderer, this produces:

```
<table id="answer_1" class="marginLeft1a">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="answer_1:0" type="radio" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'probeDiv2')" value="0" name="answer_1">
        <label for="answer_1:0"> Yes</label>
      </td><td>
         <input id="answer_1:1" type="radio" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'probeDiv2')" value="1" name="answer_1">
         <label for="answer_1:1"> No</label>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

and all is well. The ajax request is posted and my server side listener gets fired.

The relevant parts of my custom renderer:

```
 public void encodeEnd(final FacesContext p_context, final UIComponent p_component) throws IOException {

    /* set up convenience fields */
    context = p_context;
    component = p_component;
    componentId = component.getClientId(context);

    // rendering divs etc omitted.

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final UIComponent childComponent = iterator.next();
        // irrelevant code omited
        if ("javax.faces.SelectItem".equals(childComponent.getFamily())) {
            renderSelectItem(idIndex, childComponent);
            idIndex++;
        }
     }
 }

private void renderSelectItem(final int p_idIndex, final UIComponent p_childComponent) throws IOException {
        // unrelated code omitted
        writer.startElement("input", component);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", getInputType(), null);
        writer.writeAttribute("id", p_childComponentId, "id");
        writer.writeAttribute("name", componentId, "clientId");
        RenderKitUtils.renderSelectOnclick(context, component, false);
        writer.endElement("input");
        // unrelated code omitted
}
```

Update: The decode method in the base class for my renderer is:

```
    @Override
public void decode(final FacesContext p_context, final UIComponent p_component) {

    final Map<String, String> valuesMap = p_context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    final UIInput input = (UIInput) p_component; // NOSONAR

    final Object value = valuesMap.get(input.getClientId(p_context));
    // System.out.println("radio button decode: found " + value);
    input.setSubmittedValue(value);
}
```

This renders as :

```
<span class="marginLeft1a" id="answer_1">
    <label for="answer_1:0">
    <input type="radio" value="0" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'probeDiv2')" name="answer_1" id="answer_1:0"> 
     Yes
     </label>
     <label for="answer_1:1">
       <input type="radio" value="1" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'probeDiv2')" name="answer_1" id="answer_1:1"> 
       No
     </label>
</span>
```

As you can see, the javaScript click handler is identical, as are the name and id attribute values of the input tags. Although this triggers the Ajax request, the listener is not fired server side as it is with the first version.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `decode()` method is responsible for finding and queueing ajax events. I'm however not seeing this in your code snippet. Am I right to assume that you actually have none and therefore you're facing this problem? In any case, what superclass is your custom renderer extending from?

Comment: Ooops, my bad. I've updated the question to show the decode method. I guess I need some event code there eh? Help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`decode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html#decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) method of the [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html) (or [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) if there's no renderer) is supposed to decode the ajax request based on `javax.faces.behavior.event` request parameter and trigger [`ClientBehavior#decode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehavior.html#decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) on the matching client behaviors.

Basically, the logic is as follows:

```
Map<String, List<ClientBehavior>> behaviors = ((ClientBehaviorHolder) component).getClientBehaviors();

if (!behaviors.isEmpty()) {
    Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String behaviorEvent = params.get("javax.faces.behavior.event");

    if (behaviorEvent != null) {
        List<ClientBehavior> behaviorsForEvent = behaviors.get(behaviorEvent);

        if (behaviorsForEvent != null && !behaviorsForEvent.isEmpty()) {
           String behaviorSource = params.get("javax.faces.source");

           if (isBehaviorSource(context, behaviorSource, component.getClientId())) {
               for (ClientBehavior behavior: behaviorsForEvent) {
                   behavior.decode(context, component);
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Given the fact that you're using `RenderKitUtils` and the generated HTML output contains `mojarra.ab()`, I'll assume that you're using Mojarra. In that case, it's perhaps wiser to extend your custom renderer from [`RadioRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/RadioRenderer.java#RadioRenderer) instead which has all this logic already implemented in [`HtmlBasicRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicRenderer.java#HtmlBasicRenderer.decodeBehaviors%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) and [`SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.java#SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.isBehaviorSource%28com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FacesContext,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) so that you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Looking promising, however `isBehaviorSource(context, behaviorSource, component.getClientId()` is returning false as behaviourSource is answer_1:0 and clientId is answer_1 - I'm trying to step through the normal renderer in debug to see how that works, and to educate myself further. Fascinating stuff.

Comment: Right, better extend from `SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer` (or `RadioRenderer`) instead, it has the right `isBehaviorSource()` logic implemented.

Comment: Legend! Once again, you've proved invaluable! I think it's about time I showed my thanks to you for all the fantastic help you've given me  in my JSF journey both directly and indirectly. Check your email ;)

Comment: One more really quick one if I may, looking through the default RadioRenderer class, I see `        RequestStateManager.set(context,
                RequestStateManager.TARGET_COMPONENT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
                component);` which I am not doing ion my own renderer - should I be doing so? is this something to do with REST api (which we're not using) or something more important?

Comment: No, is for Mojarra internal optimizations. This is used in `PropertyEditorHelper#getComponent()`. Feel free to keep it in.